# Why Do i get null value in the following code concerning java inheritence

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I will provide the code and the output given by the compiler for better understanding of the problem. You will notice a null value for Registration Number...there is the problem.
You will notice at the output that i get null value for Registration number...i don't get it because it all seemed right, until it wasn't.

```java
public class Student {
    private String regNo;
    //Student student = new Test();

    public String getRegNo() {
        return regNo;
    }

    public void setRegNo(String number) {
        this.regNo = regNo;
    }

    public void displayRegistrationNumber(){
        System.out.println("Registration number: "+ getRegNo());
    }

}

-----------------------------------------------------------------'
public class Test extends Student{
    private double sub1, sub2;


    public double getSub1() {
        return sub1;
    }

    public void setSub1(double sub1) {
        this.sub1 = sub1;
    }

    public double getSub2() {
        return sub2;
    }

    public void setSub2(double sub2) {
        this.sub2 = sub2;
    }

    public void displayScore(){
        System.out.printf("Scores: Subject1 = %.0f, Subject2 = %.0f \n",getSub1(), getSub2());
    }
}

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
public class Results extends Test {
    private double total;

    public double getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(double total) {
        this.total = total;
    }


    public void displayTotalScores(){
        setTotal(getSub1()+getSub2());
        System.out.printf("Total marks: %.0f \n", getTotal());
    }

}
---------------------------------------------------------------------

public class Main_method {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Results results = new Results();

        results.setRegNo("2017-04-06859");
        results.setSub1(75.47);
        results.setSub2(89);


        results.displayRegistrationNumber();
        results.displayScore();
        results.displayTotalScores();

    }
}
```

Here's the output. Notice the null

```
Registration number: null
Scores: Subject1 = 75, Subject2 = 89 
Total marks: 164 `
```

Comment: The parameter `number` in `setRegNo` is **unused**, and the statement `this.regNo = regNo` means `this.regNo = this.regNo` since there is no other `regNo` in scope. Rename the parameter to `regNo`.

Comment: Note that this is a bad example of inheritance, because a test is not a kind of student. A test has-a (belongs to) a student.

Comment: Sure, thanks. It was just a tutorial question posted by our lecturer after he finished teaching about inheritance and polymorphism. I was unaware that i passed number instead of regNo in the setter method of registration number. There was my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Here instead of assigning `parameter number` to `regNo` you just reassigned its own value (which is null initially) to it:

```
public void setRegNo(String number) {
    this.regNo = regNo;
}
```

so change it to:

```
this.regNo = number;
```

Comment: Oh my God...what a mistake it was. Thank you all for the correction on my code. I used auto-generate feature in intelliJ Idea to add set and get methods to my private variables hence i think i must have messed up with something there unknowingly after the setRegno() method had been created.

Comment: @Abdul-razaqTwaha my pleasure, if this answer helped you resolve your problems, then you can mark it  as accepted

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behavior, the argument you passed to   `public void setRegNo(String number)` is never used.

```
 this.regNo = regNo;
```

reassigns the the regNo  declared in `Student` class (which in this case is `null` ) back to the Object which calls it.

change the argument or the assignment statement

i.e

```
 public void setRegNo(String regNo)
```

or

```
this.regNo = number;
```